# Syntax error in MySQL statement, unhelpful error message

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL server and I am trying to use

```
INSERT INTO servers (ip, version, motd, players, plugins, time)
VALUES ('--.---.---.--', '1.13.2', 'redacted', '0', '1', NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE;
```

to insert data, but this error message popped up:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I tried this query again on LibreOffice Base and these messages popped up:

> SQL Status: HY000 
>   Error code: 1000
>   Syntax error in SQL statement
>
> SQL Status: HY000
>   Error code: 1000
>   syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting BETWEEN or IN or SQL_TOKEN_LIKE

Any help?

Comment: Does `redacted` contain a single quote? Can you show your actual code?

Comment: On duplicate key update what? Is that your complete insert statement?

Comment: @FrankerZ It only contains alphabet and spaces, the string is escaped

Comment: This needs a [mcve].

Comment: @P.Salmon yes it is, just realized the mistake, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Missing statement after on duplicate update

Comment: Yeah, MySQL is asking "on duplication update...what?"